# Embedding Wave Dashboard on Lightning Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, einstein-analytics

We have a Wave dashboard embedded on a Lightning and Classic page.

We need to filter this dashboard to only display data relevant to a specific Contact.

This works fine in Classic, but Lightning gives us the following error when adding the the json to the page component: Error: The filter for this dashboard is invalid.

Provide a valid filter in JSON The JSON is: { "ithSales": { "Contact.Id":["$contact_18di___c"] } }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't apply filters directly with Lightning.

You will need to create a VF page and apply the filters using that. See [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/119813/filters-embedded-wave-dashboards) post for reference. So, it would look something like

```
<apex:page sidebar="true" standardController="account">

  <wave:dashboard dashboardId="0FKB000000006Y7OAI" 
        showTitle="true" 
        height="475px" 
        openLinksInNewWindow="true" 
        filter="{'opportunities': {'Id': ['{!Account.Id}']}}" />

</apex:page>
```

This will ensure filters are interpreted correctly. See [this](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=bi_embed_vf.htm&language=en_US) link for more details.